# Erorr in python using both split and while loop and external text file

Tags: python

I'm new to Python and so am confused by the following "list index out of range" error I get with the following code as my text file only contains 4 items in it which are first name, last name, hourly salary, total hours worked. Should this be changed to something that's not a while loop? If need be I can give the entire code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
while line2 != "":
    line2 = " "
    line2 = line2.split( " " )
    if (line2[ 0 ]+ " " + line2[ 1 ]) != name1.rstrip( " \n " ):
    empFile3.write(line2[ 0 ] + " " + line2[ 1 ] + " " + line2[ 2 ] + " " + line2[ 3 ] + " \n " )
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in line no. 2. Remove that. You are getting that error because you are trying to split an empty string.

```
while line2 != "":
    line2 = line2.split( " " )
    if (line2[ 0 ]+ " " + line2[ 1 ]) != name1.rstrip( " \n " ):
       empFile3.write(line2[ 0 ] + " " + line2[ 1 ] + " " + line2[ 2 ] + " " + line2[ 3 ] + " \n " )
```

Comment: Hi and thank you. I removed line no. 2 and am still getting the error. Should I be using a "for" loop instead? Sorry in advance for the newbie question.

Comment: Sorry, am getting the following error, "'list' object has no attribute 'split".

Comment: You cannot split a list object. Split can only be used on a string. If you have a list of string them loop over the list and use split. 
For example: [x.split(" ") for x in list]

Comment: Thank you, Ashok. I'm new to Python and am trying to make sense of it all. Thank you for your example, that helps out a lot.